# How to hide collection view when table view is searching?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image]

I have collection view inside of my first table view cell. Search bar at the top of the table view (out of table view). Collection views showing as table view cell items count at `viewDidLoad()`. E.g. If table view cell items count 4 so collection view items count as same 4.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!

var imageNames = [ImageNames]()
var priceFood: [Double]!
var searchFoods = [String]()
var filtered = [String]()
var searching = false


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    let foodCell = Food(name: ["Hamburger big mac",
                               "Patates",
                               "Whopper",
                               "Steakhouse"], price: [15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0])

    searchBar.delegate = self

    searchFoods = foodCell.name
    priceFood = foodCell.price

    imageNames = [
        ImageNames(name: "images"),
        ImageNames(name: "unnamed"),
        ImageNames(name: "unnamed")
        //            ImageNames(name: "images"),
        //            ImageNames(name: "images")
    ]

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
     return filtered.count
    } else {
     return searchFoods.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainFoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTableViewCell

        //            cell.mainFoodCollectionView.delegate = self
        //            cell.mainFoodCollectionView.dataSource = self
        //            cell.mainFoodCollectionView.reloadData()
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellForFood", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTitleTableViewCell

        if searching {
            cell.titleLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
            cell.priceLabel?.text = priceFood[indexPath.row].description
        } else {
            cell.titleLabel?.text = searchFoods[indexPath.row]
            cell.priceLabel?.text = priceFood[indexPath.row].description
        }
        return cell
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 130 : 65
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 100 : 65
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  imageNames.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 130)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainFoodCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodCollectionViewCell
    let img = imageNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.mainFoodImage.image = UIImage(named: img.name)
    return cell
}
}

extension MainViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    mainTableView.reloadData()
   }
```

I think I did not make sense with this function

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = searchText.isEmpty ? searchFoods : filtered.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
        return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
    //        filtered = self.searchFoods.filter ({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
    searching = true
    mainTableView.reloadData()

}
}
```

Comment: Wait so are you just trying to hide the collection view. If so just use collectionView.isHidden = true

Comment: Partly yes but how can I hide in `searchBar(:, textDidChange)` method?

Comment: Well I haven’t really worked with search bars but I’m guessing you can just put it in there while searching = true

Comment: If I hide collection cells their height or size placing there with view background :)

Comment: I’m not sure then. Sorry :(

Comment: You said that you have collection view inside first table view cell, but you your code shows that it is not `if indexPath.section == 0 {`. you check for section not for row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainFoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTableViewCell
    cell.mainFoodCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell

} else {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellForFood", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTitleTableViewCell

    if searching {
        cell.titleLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel?.text = priceFood[indexPath.row].description
    } else {
        cell.titleLabel?.text = searchFoods[indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel?.text = priceFood[indexPath.row].description
    }
    return cell
}

}
```

Solved my problem